# Pandas pct_change gives slightly different answers to manual

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Can anyone explain why the pct_change function gives slightly different numbers when using the more manual calculation:

pct_change function:

```
print(prices)
         0                                                                    
0   1035.23                                                                    
1   1032.47                                                                    


print(prices.pct_change(1))

          0                                                                   
0        NaN                                                                   
1  -0.002666
```

More manual function

```
(prices - prices.shift(1))/prices

          0                                                                   
0        NaN                                                                   
1  -0.002673
```

What is the reason behind the difference here?

Comment: In this formula `(prices - prices.shift(1))/prices` you should be dividing by `prices.shift(1))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is second formula is wrong:

```
prices = pd.DataFrame({0:[1035.23,1032.47]})
print (prices)

print(prices.pct_change(1))
          0
0       NaN
1 -0.002666

print(prices/(prices.shift())-1)
          0
0       NaN
1 -0.002666
```

As pointed [Andrew L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437284/pandas-pct-change-gives-slightly-different-answers-to-manual/45437355#comment77835509_45437284) in comment:

```
print((prices - prices.shift(1))/prices.shift(1))
          0
0       NaN
1 -0.002666
```